# ResourceManager.GetResourceSet additional namespace suffix .resources

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I am trying to acquire resource by resourcefilename and key this way:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("B2B.Portal.Resources.Views." + viewType, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var res = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
```

I am getting this error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture. Make sure
>   "B2B.Portal.Resources.Views.CustomerPurchaseOrders.resource" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly "B2B.Portal" at compile
>   time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.

How can I make it stop adding '.resources' suffix or maybe this is not the issue?

Edit:
forgot to mention: these are manually added localization resources

Comment: That suffix is always present, generated by Resgen.exe.  You guessed at the name incorrectly, a very common problem and the core reason that Microsoft added the Resource Designer.  We can't guess at it either, use `ildasm.exe` and look at the manifest.  You'll see the proper name in one of the .resource directives.  With non-zero odds that you don't find it at all if you "manually" added resources.  Use standard .NET localization techniques, you'll have good odds for a lot more trouble when your localization services gets it wrong as well because it is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not exactly answer to my question but it is an alternative solution:

```
Type.GetType("B2B.Portal.Resources.View." + viewType + "." + viewType).GetProperty(col.Name).GetValue(null, null).ToString()
```